# Obtaining Username from Python in React

Tags: python, reactjs, database, endpoint

I have a python project that i use for logging in a user and authentication purposes. I successfully connected it to my React project, so now my React frontend displays content depending if the user is logged in or not.
My issue is, I fail to realize how to display the username that the user used to log in to their account.

This is in my react:

```
clientId: my client id from the db,
authorizationEndpoint: the OAuth authorization endpoint,
tokenEndpoint: The token endpint,
redirectUri: my path to react after authorization,
```

This is the dependency I use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oauth2-code-pkce

My data is not JWT, so I figure that I should not use

```
// An object with all the properties encoded in the token (username, email, etc)
  tokenData?: TTokenData
```

and

```
// Whether or not to decode the access token (should be set to 'false' if the access token is not a JWT (e.g. from Github))
// If `false`, 'tokenData' will be 'undefined' from the <AuthContext>
  decodeToken?: boolean  // default: true
```

Please guide me on how to achieve my goal. Thanks.

This is the process:

1. The user presses `Log In` in react webpage.
2. They are taken to a log in form in python.
3. They enter username and password.
4. They authorize the log in in python by pressing `authorize`.
5. They are redirected back to react where they see the content which they did not see before authorization.

Now, I want to be able to see the `username` in my react frontend.

Comment: So the username must somehow be part of the data that the user receives in response to being logged in…!? How exactly does the login work? What does the user receive as token of them being authenticated?

Comment: @deceze yes there is a token for each login. It is in the dependency link that I posted. and I know that it works because I log it in the console in my react and it matches it to the token in the db.

Comment: What have you learned about that dependency that you can tell us, without us having to go out of our way to try to figure something out about some library that you're using?

Comment: @deceze it is for authentication and authorization for OAuth with PKCE. It simply gets the credentials of the db and by wrapping it around the react App, the react app is enabled to use it. The dependency has `tokenData` that holds the user's info such as username and email. The thing is, the dependency says to use `tokdenData`, it must be decoded through `decodeToken`. And `decodeToken` only accepts JWT. That is where all the problem lies, based on my assumption.